# Neovim on Windows can't find python provider

Tags: python, neovim

I'm trying to install neovim on Windows and import my previous init.vim file.
I've previously defined my snippets in ultisnips.
I'm using windows and ahve tested this in another version of windows and it works, however, at the moment when I run

```
:checkhealth
```

I get the following error:

```
## Python 3 provider (optional) 
30   - WARNING: No Python executable found that can `import neovim`. Using the first available executable for diagnostics.                                          
31   - ERROR: Python provider error:                                                                                                                                
32     - ADVICE:                                                                                                                                                    
33       - provider/pythonx: Could not load Python 3:                                                                                                               
34           python3 not found in search path or not executable.                                                                                                    
35           python3.7 not found in search path or not executable.                                                                                                  
36           python3.6 not found in search path or not executable.                                                                                                  
37           python3.5 not found in search path or not executable.                                                                                                  
38           python3.4 not found in search path or not executable.                                                                                                  
39           python3.3 not found in search path or not executable.                                                                                                  
40           python not found in search path or not executable.                                                                                                     
41   - INFO: Executable: Not found
```

But I do have python 3.7 installed. I can run python in cmd / powershell, and I can import neovim python module without any issues. Does someone know how to get neovim to pick up python?

Comment: are you sure you python3 folder is in your path? and where is it installed?

Answer (score 12):

**Make sure you have Python3 installed, the following answer also works with Python2.**

Check for help:

```
:help provider-python
```

Go to the `PYTHON QUICKSTART` and you will see one of this two options:

- For Python 2 plugins:
- For Python 3 plugins:

*Because you're problem is with python 3 follow this steps that are mentioned in* `For Python 3 plugins:`

```
1. Make sure Python 3.4+ is available in your $PATH.
2. Install the module (try "python" if "python3" is missing): >
   python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pynvim
```

This should fix the problem, if it persist then make sure the right path is being used, go to `~/.vimrc` and add the following:

For python3:

```
let g:python3_host_prog = '/path/to/python3'
```

For Python2:

```
let g:python_host_prog  = '/path/to/python'
```

Note: I found this in `PYTHON QUICKSTART` if you continue reading you will find it.

### To know the location of python use:

- For Linux and Mac

```sh
which python3
```

- For [windows](https://datatofish.com/locate-python-windows/)

Use `:checkhealth` again and it should output the following:

```
## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/usr/local/bin/python3"
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/local/bin/python3
  - INFO: Python version: 3.9.1
  - INFO: pynvim version: 0.4.2
  - OK: Latest pynvim is installed.
```

Comment: For windows you should be able to use `where` instead of which, worked for me personally. But I've seen some other posts which state where isn't the best

Comment: @karizma That's why I put a link instead of the actual command.

Comment: For anyone struggling whit it, you actually need to point to the actual executable, not only the path, e.g.:  let g:python3_host_prog = 'C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'

Comment: This solution DOES NOT work for me, even after the edit in the last comment of @Balu

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that neovim is confusing python 2 and python 3 somehow. For me it worked just to have renamed python executable in PATH of python 2, that is python.exe -> python2.exe, and now it seems to work fine. However it is maybe not the perfect solution.

Answer (score -1):

1. Locate the path to the python3 executable using [one of these methods](https://datatofish.com/locate-python-windows/). Copy the path. For me, it was *C:\Users\money\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310*.
2. Then, add this directory to your PATH variable. Search for "View advanced system settings" > "Environment Variables" > "System Variables" > "Path" > "Edit" > "New" and paste the directory there , save and exit.
3. You should be able run python commands from the terminal now.
4. Install the neovim python module by doing `pip3 install pynvim` in the terminal.

Try `:checkhealth provider` again. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved this problem. So let me say what I did.

In the beginning, I used the `python3.8.8`, which will create the same issues. I tried to `pip install neovim` and failed.

Then I replace the `python3.8.8` with `python3.8.1`. Everything is OK~

So change the version of Python?