# How can I get neovim on windows to recognize python?

Tags: python, neovim

I think I'm not supposed to ask questions in other questions. This didn't answer my question [Neovim on Windows can't find python provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160481/neovim-on-windows-cant-find-python-provider)

When I start neovim it says no python provider found. Run ":checkhealth provider".

checkhealth provider shows it found python 3 and that latest pynvim is installed. it also shows that python 2 is disabled (I set g:loaded_python_provider=0). I've also made a symbolic link to python.exe called python3.exe.

How can I get past this point?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a package that tell neovim how to use python. On arch Linux I had to install a package called `python-neovim-git`.

From what I've seen on windows, you probably need to install `pynvim`.

Comment: checkhealth provider reports that the latest version of pynvim is installed.

Comment: I've worked around the problem by installing python 2.7. 2 and 3 are on the system path so python2.exe, pytyon3.exe, pip2.exe and pip3.exe are found... I don't think this should be the answer though.