# Curl error setting up Python 3 provider in Neovim configuration

Tags: python, curl, neovim

I'm trying to set up my Neovim configuration using [this](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim/blob/master/init.lua) `init.lua` file. However, the LSP support for Python doesn't seem to be working.

As indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65996328/21423194) answer, I've confirmed that I have `pynvim` installed and set `vim.g.python3_host_prog` (in `init.lua`) as the location to my Python 3.11 executable.

When running `:checkhealth provider`, I get a message confirming that `provider-python` has found both my Python executable and the `pynvim` package. I also get the following error message:

```
WARNING: Could not contact PyPI to get latest version.
ERROR: HTTP request failed: error: curl error with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynvim/json: 60
```

I've already tried running `curl -V` on my terminal, which confirmed that HTTPS is supported. I've also visited the URL on my browser and verified that it's working.

**Edit:** I tried running `curl https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynvim/json` from the directory where `curl.exe` and `curl-ca-bundle.crt` are stored and I got the following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in 
certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore 
could not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about 
this situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your dns.

I had to set my dns to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 as a work around for cmake.

Once I set it back to default, it fixed the curl error.